# How to slice a list in Python without copying the reference?

Tags: python, list, slice

I need to remove the first N elements from a list inside a function and I want the original list to be modified. What is a concise way to do this in Python?

Using a `slice` isn't working because the slice operation returns a separate reference to the list. In this example, I would like `pkt` to be `[3,4,5]` after calling the function.

```
>>>> def process_packet(packet, num_bytes):
         # ...
         packet = packet[num_bytes:len(packet)]
         print packet

>>> pkt = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> process_packet(pkt, 2)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> print pkt
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `packet[:] = packet[num_bytes:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slice notation inside:

```
def process_packet(packet, num_bytes):
    packet[:] = packet[num_bytes:len(packet)]
    print packet

>>> pkt = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> process_packet(pkt, 2)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> print pkt
[3, 4, 5]
```

Note that this works only if `packet` is a list or compatible iterable. The initial and final length of the list may be different, (larger and smaller, or vice verse are fine).

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `del` to delete slices in place :)

```
>>> def process_packet(packet, num_bytes):
...     del packet[num_bytes:len(packet)]
... 
>>> a = range(10)
>>> process_packet(a,4)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: With a docstring that says "THIS WILL MODIFY YOUR INPUT LIST" or similar... something subtle anyway. I'd also consider changing the name to `alter_` or similar to make it clearer...

Comment: @JonClements Right, that's a good advice. I merely copied the bare minimum lines (& the name) from the code above. Hope he is doing that already in his production code. :)

Comment: Glad to learn about `del`. In this case `del packet[0:num_bytes]` would match the functionality in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return packet` at the end of your function.

And when you call the function call it like this: `pkt = process_packet(pkt,2)`

Comment: OP doesn't want to make a new list, though I'm not sure if list mutation is a pythonic way to things.

Comment: @MxyL they're not expressly saying they don't want a new list - more that they want the original to be updated... This does that in a round-about way :) (given the example anyway - were there other references to the list - it would invalidate my jovial response somewhat)

Comment: @JonClements You're right, I assumed the "doesn't work, returns a separate reference" part implied "we don't want a copy"

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a deque from the collections module, and popleft num_bytes of times, or create a class that modifies self.pkt, or the simplest way is this:

```
def process_packet(pkt, num):
    return pkt[num:]

pkt = process_packet(pkt, 2)
```

Just return the packet, and reassign over it. This is probably what you would see the most to handle this sort of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer to [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). There you will find what you need to understand how Python pass arguments to functions. Later you will find the answer to your question by your self.